# array not working outside of function

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var vocabWords = [];
//display each vocab words
$.getJSON("getData.php", function (data) {

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        vocabWords.push({
            'id': val['id'],
            'audioURL': val['audioURL']
        });
        setTimeout(function () { //onclick="play_sound(\''+val['audioURL']+'\');" 
            $(".vocab-list").append($('<li onclick="play_sound(\'' + val['audioURL'] + '\');"  class="vocab-word" id="vocab_' + val['id'] + '"><img width="230px" height="230px" src="' + val['imageURL'] + '" /><div><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>' + val['word'] + '</div></li>').hide().fadeIn(600));
            play_sound(val['audioURL']);
        }, key * 3000);
    });
    alert(vocabWords[2]['audioURL']);

}); //end display vocab words

alert(vocabWords[2]['audioURL']);
```

The first `alert()` works... and shows the correct information but the second one doesnt ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `$.getJSON` method is asynchronous. It doesn't block the execution of the code after it. The `$.each` code in the callback is executed only after the JSON request is made. The second alert is actually happening before the first (line-of-code-wise). `vocabWords` is empty for the line "after" `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 2):

What it looks like to me: the getJSON() function is asynchronous and calls the provided function when it receives data. The second alert() is called immediately, which is almost certainly before the data is returned.

In other words, here's the order things are happening in:

1. getJSON() called
2. second alert() called
3. data arrives
4. function with first alert() called

Comment: Thanks, i think i keep thinking javascript is procedural! How would I get around this?

Comment: @Jake: Switch to `$.get()` and supply `async: false` as an option.

Comment: @Jake Javascript is "procedural" - however you want to qualify that term, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is asynchronous in nature. Meaning that first alert fires *before* data has been received from the server (getData.php).

This is because the call fires, and lets javascript know it will complete the callback function when the server actually returns a response.

A cleaner way to do this would be with a promise object - take a look at those - the below code uses a promise

```
$.when($.getJSON('url',function(data){
  // do stuff to data in here

}).done(function(){
 // carry on normal execution flow here

});
```

This is useful if you need to ensure a response before carrying on what you were doing previously, though it might not be best practise.

Answer (score 0):

Making HTTP-Requests in JavaScript/jQuery is **asynchronous** by default. This means, that you cannot read this as sequential code.

The function you create in the getJSON call is not executed immediately. It gets called once the request successfully returns. However, the 2nd alert gets executed right after you started the request, which hasn't returned by then.